# Android:Service Activity Start and Stop Control

Tags: android, service, android-activity

Hello Android Gurus
For API Level 7 and Above-->
I am badly struck trying to figure out a solution for the following problem:

I have an activity which i would use to Kick start an Service. This is an infinite loop service which can run forever. I would like to disconnect the Service from Activity and at a later point of time i will call the activity again which should tell me the current state of Service and i can Stop the service.

Is something like this possible. Right now my Service is Sticky and i am not able to Close the activity as Service is running for ever and i am also not able to Stop the service from activity.

Code samples would be of great help!!! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple questions:

1. You can disconnect/reconnect from the Service using `bind`. Unfortunately the best advice to give there is to carefully read the documentation for Service at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html: look carefully at the Local Service example, as it demonstrates what you need to do to bind/unbind to a sticky service.
2. To stop it, once you've bound you can call [stopSelf](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29).

Comment: I did not get the information needed to detach the service from Activity.After i start the service from activity i need to close the activity and keep the service running... Is something like this possible in Android???I would need more help here

Comment: Yes. If you start the service with STICKY, when you call `unbind` the Activity will disconnect and the Service will continue running. You can then call `bind` the next time the Activity starts.

Comment: Thanks Femi...for the help...i will start the service with startservice and then call unbindservice to disconnect..i hope it works :)thanks again , greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Start the service non sticky from the Activity.

In the service control the flow logically, say calling `onStart()` to keep it running.
Call `onDestroy()` when you have to stop.